# Not able to set Launch Image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, launchimage, launch-screen

I am a newbie in iOS. I want to set Launch Image in my app. And I'm using Asset Catalog. And I know I have to drag and drop the image to the boxes that shows up when I'm using Asset Catalog. But a weird thing which is happening at that time is when I'm trying to drag-drop, it just comes back . As if Xcode is telling me NO PLACE HERE. Xcode doesn't let me set my Launch Images. I'm not able to DROP my images in those boxes. And I know the sizes of my images are quite correct. 640*960, 640*1136, 750*1334, 1242*2208.(And I don't want to use LaunchScreen because it only supports iOS 8 and later.)

It's even more weird that people are down voting without even telling the reason. (If you are not good enough to help at least don't discourage newbies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution.

Just answering my question so that if anyone is having same problem then here is the solution. My problem was because by mistake I was using images of "jpg" format where in fact I should have used "png" . Now I'm using "png" and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Click on images.xcassets. You should see app icon in the list. At the bottom of that column there is a plus and minus button. Click the plus button.

[image]

Click on new Launch Image in the list. This covers iPad's and iPhone's from iOS 5-8 and covers portrait and landscape.

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm saying when I am trying to drag-drop my image in those boxes the image comes back to the folder. Not able to drop the images in those boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Launch screen can also be support for ios 8,
What you need to do set the Go to project->Media.xcassets on right side information tab you need to select iOS 7.0 and later sizes.
Then you set your launch screen inside the Launch images.
It will work definitely.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. I'm not getting you.

Comment: Click on project file->general tab->App icon and Launch image  then select on the right side info tab select ios 7 and later size in that.

Then go to the launchImage source drag and drop your images there.
If there is already images then delete first then drag and drop.

Comment: I know that brother. As I have mentioned I know I have to drag drop it. My real problem was Image wasn't getting set into those boxes. Anyway I have got the solution now. Check my answer. If you want to exactly know what my problem was then just try to set a jpg file for your Launch Image. Anyways thanx for your time and input.

Answer (score 0):

By apple provide the document [Adding an iOS App Icon Set or Launch Image Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

open `Images.xcassets` of your project

Drag file one by one on boxes  as per its `size`.

See following image.

[image]

After doing all Remove `LaunchScreen.xib` file from your project

And remove `Launch screen interface file base name` from your plist file.

[image]